# How to read null terminated strings in pairs using bash

Tags: bash

Let say, have a command `genpairs` which generates null-terminated strings.

```
key1 \0 val1 \0 key2 \0 val2 \0
```

Want read the above input into bash variables in pairs. The following not works for me:

```
genpairs() { #for the demo
    printf "%d\0x\0" 1
    printf "%d\0y\0" 2
    printf "%d\0z\0" 3
}
#the above generates 1  \0   x  \0   2  \0   y  \0   3  \0   z  \0 etc...
while IFS= read -r -d '' key val; do
        echo "key:[$key] val:[$val]"
done < <(genpairs)
```

prints

```
key:[1] val:[]
key:[x] val:[]
key:[2] val:[]
key:[y] val:[]
key:[3] val:[]
key:[z] val:[]
```

e.g. the read somewhat doesn't split on the `$'\0'` into two variables.

The wanted output:

```
key:[1] val:[x]
key:[2] val:[y]
key:[3] val:[z]
```

**How to read null-terminated input into multiple variables?**

EDITED the OP's question - added a better demo - x y z

I can solve it as:

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' inp; do
        if (( n % 2 ))
        then
                val="$inp"
                echo "key:[$key] val:[$val]"
        else
                key="$inp"
        fi
        let n++
done < <(genpairs)
```

This prints the

```
key:[1] val:[x]
key:[2] val:[y]
key:[3] val:[z]
```

but it looks to me really terrible solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use two `read` statements:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' val; do
    echo "key:[$key] val:[$val]"
done < <(genpairs)
```

---

Using Bash≥4.4, you can also use `mapfile` with its `-d` switch:

```
while mapfile -n 2 -d '' ary && ((${#ary[@]}>=2)); do
    echo "key:[${ary[0]}] val:[${ary[1]}]"
done < <(genpairs)
```

Comment: WHY I need ask for such simple solutions... :( Feels stupid. Thanx a lot!!!